# Does the bigquery Simba JDBC driver support batch queries?

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery

Does the Simba driver google offers [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers/) support batch query jobs? I don't see it in the driver documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean submit a query using batch priority?  I don't believe so, and there's no reference to the capability in the [odbc config reference](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/linux/content/odbc/bq/options/options-general.htm) under either general or advanced.

It may be worth [filing a BigQuery feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0).  If you do so, please provide additional details around how you'd use such functionality.